# Generating the series of two brackets multiplied by each other

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im trying to expand: $ (1+2x)^5 (2+x)^6$
to obtain the constants from its expansion $a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3$
What do I do? As far as I know you can't generate a series for each part seperately and then multiply the series

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem? $$ \begin{align} (a+b)^6 & = \binom 6 0 a^6 + \binom 6 1 a^5 b + \binom 6 2 a^4 b^2 + \binom 6 3 a^3 b^3 + \binom 6 4 a^2 b^4 + \binom 6 5 a b^5 + \binom 6 6 b^6 \\  \\ & = a^6 +6a^5 b + 15a^4b^2 + 20 a^3b^3 + 15a^2b^4 + 6ab^5 + b^6 \end{align} $$

Comment: as far as i know the problem only asks me to find those 4 constants. my problem isnt that i dont know how to expand them individually its that i need to generste a series for the entire function

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just expand the two binomials and multiply them. Note that by the Binomial Theorem
$$(1+2x)^5 (2+x)^6=\left(\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}2^kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^6\binom{6}{j}2^{6-j}x^j\right).$$
Therefore
$$[x^n](1+2x)^5 (2+x)^6=\sum_{n=k+j\\0\leq k\le 5\\0\leq j\le 6}\binom{5}{k}\binom{6}{j}2^{6-j+k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& (1+2x)^5 (2+x)^6 \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( 1 + 12x + 60 x^2 + 160 x^3 + \cdots \right) \left( 64 + 192 x + 240 x^2 + 160 x^3 + \cdots \right) \\
& \qquad \text{by the binomial theorem} \\[10pt]
= {} & (1\cdot64) + (1\cdot 192 + 12\cdot64) x + (1\cdot240 + 12\cdot192 + 60\cdot64) x^2 \\
& {} + (1\cdot160 + 12\cdot240 + 60\cdot192 + 160\cdot64) x^3 + \cdots
\end{align}